# Directory Not Found Exception after publishing

Tags: c#

I'm developing a windows form application that has different features, one of these features is that the user has the ability to generate a receipt file in a pdf format.

The Problem I'm facing now is that when I run the application from visual studio this feature works perfectly, but when I publish and run the application in my pc and in other pcs the following error pops-up:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\B8GVHPQK.4RG\XND3YQM7.9AB\hsar..tion_5a44077fdab68dde_0002.0000_e0623e33977d687d\TempReceipts
>   at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
>   at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean isDirectory)
>   at System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity..ctor(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections) 
>   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl()

The error tells that the directory, where the receipts are stored, is can't be found, while in visual studio the there is no such error.

I've read a little about and some said that this is occurred because of permissions restrictions, I've tried to use the following code to grant the WRITE permissions in the targeted directory, but still facing the same error:

```
AddDirectorySecurity("TempReceipts", @"Resources\\TempReceipts", FileSystemRights.WriteData, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

Here is the method:

```
public static void AddDirectorySecurity(string FileName, string Account, FileSystemRights Rights, AccessControlType ControlType)
    {
        // Create a new DirectoryInfo object.
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FileName);

        // Get a DirectorySecurity object that represents the 
        // current security settings.
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings. 
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, Rights, ControlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

    }
```

so could anyone please suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: Could you also add the code you've used to create the directory path.... and the line of code that's throwing the exception

Comment: Thanks!!, you gave me a great hint!!!, actually I've created the directory manually in the bin/debug directory!!, Now I've tried to create the directory path from inside the code and it worked perfectly !! many thanks again!

Comment: The problem is your logic to store application data in subfolders of the application folder- There is a dedicated folder for this: Look at how to use _[Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)_ and company

Comment: hahaha, no problem. with directory errors always check that first... it's caught me out a few times

Comment: @Steve that's a good point, actually I'm new to programming, I will look out for it, thanks dear